# Is there a way to have a minimum distance between a ranged slider's points be something like an hour in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, slider

[image: A photo of my current ranged slider]

I'm looking for a way to make it so that the user can only make the time duration larger than an hour. Also is there a way of displaying the times other than in a label so that the user doesn't have to be holding on the dot to see them? It'd be preferable to be able to change it by typing a time in and the slider changes but it's no worries if not.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can set the divisions property to 24,to make the division to be 1hr.
2. call `setstate()` in the onchanged property to show the value outside the slider.
3. or call `setstate()` outside to set the value property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In part one, I wanted the user to be able to select - for example - 10:30 - 11:30 or 10:00 - 12:30. Is there any other way of going about this? Thanks again!

Comment: you can check the value at onchangeStart and onChangeEnd , if the newValue-oldValue isn't larger than 1hr , set the value to the old one

Answer (score 0):

In the `onChanged` method you could put an if statement to check the difference between the two values is not less an hour. If they are then do not update the values.